# anonymous class property & cannot find declaration PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

PHPStorm 2016.2.1 не может найти свойство (Ctrl+Left Mouse)
Пример

```
$data = new class {
   public $current_page = 0;
};

$data->current_page; // Клик приводит к ошибке Cannot find declaration to go to
```

Поможет ли в этом случае phpdoc или это сугубо проблема шторма ?

Comment: Я может что-то не понимаю но как мы можем обратиться к свойству объекта класса без его экземпляра?

Comment: '$data = new class{};' пожалуйста, вот вам экземпляр анонимного класса

Comment: у меня интерпретатор ругается на такую конструкцию, видимо это для совсем нового php (у меня php 5.6)

Comment: Самое время обновиться

Comment: 5.6 достаточно актуальная версия, я не думаю что на хостингах у всех поставлена версия 7.0 тем более зачем мне использовать анонимные классы когда хватает обычных за глаза

Comment: @MaximPro зачем вам вилка, ешьте ложкой.

Comment: обычные классы это не вилка!

Answer (score 1):

Как альтернативу, можете использовать, но это не всегда может помочь в случае если у вас будут не уникальные свойства

1. Выделить current_page
2. Нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>